# Is there a way to find the anomalies in an XML file without actually parsing it?

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an application that simply uploads XML files as BLOB to a DB. 
I know that there are several ways of XML validation using `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder` and then parsing it etc, but the data I'm talking about is huge and the chances of an anomaly happening in the input XML files is less..

**But, just to ensure the syntax is correct, is there a way to catch the anomalies in the files without actually parsing each file?**

Comment: To avoid creating an in-memory document, use a `SAXParser`instead. It will report well-formed viaolations and can be configured to validate, as well.

Answer (score 5):

### **No.**

Parsing, by definition, is the processing of lexical constructs in the course of creating other needed constructs.  Conformance to an expected lexical form and logical grammar is assessed, and violations are typically reported.

*All XML parsers* will assess conformance to the XML standard (***[well-formedness](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed)***); *validating XML parsers* will also assess conformance to a schema (***[validity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-valid)***).

One might choose to avoid use of an XML parser and implement a spot-check of an important lexical property of a textual object believed to be XML.  However, such a process itself would also be *parsing*; it would simply be ad hoc and generally ill advised.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of.

You could scan through the stream, checking that you are receiving valid text for the context (whether you are inside a tag, inside an entity reference, or in neither) pushing to a stack of names on each start tag and popping and checking on each end tag. If needed a bit more work can make it check namespace conformance.

This would be parsing to a limited extent (hence my saying "kind of" rather than "yes") but not actually retrieve any information from the XML (hence my saying "kind of" instead of "no").

Doing it correctly though, brings you half-way to a forward-only streaming parser. Really, unless you have some further limitations upon the content (that lets you safely take some short cuts) you'd be better off using a forward-only streaming parser for the checks; it'll be a lot less work for a lot more confidence you haven't missed some edge-case, and nearly as efficient. Since you'd be using a forward-only parser but discarding all results, the memory use should be light and the cost roughly O(1) to the size of the stream (there'd be some extra cost depending on tree depth, but minimal).